# The tab not Load

Tags: tabs, facebook-apps

I published a tab info this page https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gianluca-Bottaro/302369106525364?sk=app_323186087769261, but it not want show :-(

I controlled the setting many times, and it looks like right. 
Added a screenshot.

I asked to my provider and he said everything is ok from them side, in fact the page is shown  outside facebook.

Really need an help, it is driving me crazy!

Here a screenshot of the setting:

[image: Screenshot.]

Answer (score 0):

Check your server logs - It seems likely that your server is rejecting the POST request from Facebook and sending you to that spam page as part of your server's 403/405 error page?

Comment: It looks like it not found the page and give back the 403 page... Any solution?

Comment: Not found (404) and 403 are different things. _Looks_ like it’s what Igy said, your server refuses to accept POST requests made to .html files (which is a common setting f.e. on apache). So you have to look through your server config to see where this is blocked, or try to overwrite it in your current directory. For an apache webserver the `<Limit>` directive is your most likely candidate, maybe in combination with a `Directory` or `Location` container. I _all of this_ doesn’t ring _any_ bells for you, then talk to your server admin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove `index.html` from your Page Tab settings.

Comment: No, the tab have to refer to a page to load. It load well in other fanpages I have